# Do we need to add CSP to all web pages in a web application?

Tags: content-security-policy

We have a multi-page web application. I understand that ideally CSP should be set for text/html responses only. Is it enough to add content security policy (CSP) header to the login page or should I add the header to each & every page?

Did not find any supporting csp documentation to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that ideally CSP should be set for text/html responses only.

It does not harm to set it on every other response too, especially if it could be tricked to be rendered in HTML context.

> Is it enough to add content security policy (CSP) header to the login page or should I add the header to each & every page?

CSP gets only applied to the page where it is set. Thus if a CSP is only send for the login page it will not be applied to any other pages. Since this is probably not what you want you need to set it on every page.

> Did not find any supporting csp documentation to check this.

[MDN - Content Security Policy (CSP) - Using CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#Using_CSP) says that CSP gets only used for the page where it is set:

> Configuring Content Security Policy involves adding the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header to a web page and giving it values to control resources the user agent is allowed to load for **that** page.

Comment: Note that some browsers, notably Chrome, will have problems rendering PDF and image responses using their built-in viewers if a CSP rule blocking inline style via a `style-src` directive is enforced.